# Как выводить строчку за строкой с задержкой

Tags: c#, строки

Ребят, подскажите, что в коде не так?

По идеи он должен выводить строчку за строчкой в консоль но они появляются одновременно

```
bool b = true;
int t = 0;
int t2 = 0;

while (b)
{
    t = t + 1;
    if (t == 10000) { t = 0; t2 = t2 + 1; }

    if (t2 == 10 && t == 0) { Console.WriteLine("11111"); }
    if (t2 == 20 && t == 0) { Console.WriteLine("1111"); }
    if (t2 == 30 && t == 0) { Console.WriteLine("111"); }
    if (t2 == 40 && t == 0) { Console.WriteLine("11"); }
    if (t2 == 50 && t == 0) { Console.WriteLine("11"); }
    if (t2 == 60 && t == 0) { Console.WriteLine("1"); }
}
```

Comment: Наверное то не так, что вы пытаетесь реализовать задержку циклом, но процессор уже намного быстрей, чем в те темные века, когда задержку делали циклами.

Comment: ППЦ логика. Напомнило это:

    А как по данной методике узнать вчерашнюю дату? Очень просто!
    
    void get_yesterday_date()
    {
    sleep( 86400 ); // 60 * 60 * 24
    }

Comment: @Денис Акулов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Они появляются таки одна за одной, но программа выполняется быстро, и вы не успеваете заметить. Ваша программа выводит строчку каждые сто тысяч холостых циклов, это достаточно маленькое время на современных машинах (тем более если они оптимизированы).

Попробуйте для задержки вставить `Thread.Sleep(1000)`;

Кстати, задержки циклами считаются, как правильно пишет [[@eigenein](/users/7679/eigenein)](/users/7679/eigenein), устаревшим методом где-то по крайней мере со времён DOS. Они ненадёжны, непредсказуемы, могут быть убраны хорошим оптимизатором, и загружают процессор ненужной бессмысленной работой.

Comment: Огромное спосибо VladD!

Comment: @Денис Акулов: пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD думаю, что там даже нечего замечать. Новый запрос Writln приходит ещё до того, как завершился прежний.

Comment: @alexlz: так и есть, вывод на консоль в Windows ужасно медленный.